# MVC null list after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my post method is getting null model object (parameter) after data post.
I checked all the names of textboxes and they are like: name="Indeksy[0].min"
I tried to search many topics here, but noone helped me.
Maybe you guys have any idea, because I can'y see any error :/
Thanks in advance...

View:

```
    @model AktualnyProjekt.Models.Glowna
<div id="widelki" hidden="hidden">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        for (var k = 0; k < Model.Indeksy.Count; k++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Indeksy[k].IndeksId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].nazwa_rodzaju, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].poziom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].poziom, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].min, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].min, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].max, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].max, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Model:

```
 public class Glowna
{
    //public IEnumerable<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public IList<Indeks> Indeksy { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
   [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
          Glowna model = new Glowna();
          model.Indeksy=db.Indeksy;
          return (model);
    }


[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Glowna model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {
            foreach (Indeks item in model.Indeksy)
            {
                Indeks inde = db.Indeksy.First(x => x.IndeksId == item.IndeksId);
                inde.min = item.min;
                inde.max = item.max;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Comment: Did you check in the chrome inspector  XHR that what form data is being sent. Also Glowna the Models  Seems to have only one list property. If I were you I would have first tried the public ActionResult Index(**FormCollection** form) method and then gone ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have two forms and your *submit* button is in a different form than your data. So basically you are sending null data, because in your second form you have only the button.

So remove your second form section and move your *submit* button to the first form section.

So change this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//data
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
//submit button
}
```

by this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 //data
 //submit button
}
```

---

```
  @model AktualnyProjekt.Models.Glowna
<div id="widelki" hidden="hidden">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        for (var k = 0; k < Model.Indeksy.Count; k++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(i => i.Indeksy[k].IndeksId)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].nazwa_rodzaju, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].poziom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].poziom, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.nazwa_rodzaju, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].min, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].min, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].max, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Indeksy[k].max, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe in myself... You saved few more houres of my like. Accepted answer, TY !